# Computer won't hook up to TV through HDMI

Tags: windows-7, display, hdmi, tv

I have an Athlon based Asus motherboard with built in ATI 4500. I tried connecting it to my Samsung pn58c8000 through HDMI with no other monitor hooked up. It shows post on the TV and if I go into the BIOS I can access everything fine. Safe Mode works without a problem (full display). In normal mode it boots until Windows 7 Professional starts. It shows the progress bar, but when the Windows 7 logo is supposed to come up, it blanks out and that's it. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts:

1. It could be set to extend your desktop onto the other monitor.  Depending on how your "desktop background" is configured, that may cause it to look like a black screen.  You can test this by trying to move your cursor to the right until it shows up on the TV.  If it does, you can just right-click and select "screen resolution" (on Win7 and maybe Vista - it's "properties" on XP and older) and from there you can choose whether you're extending or duplicating.  Another way to do this is to press <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> ("p" for projector) and keep pressing P until you get to "duplicate."
2. It definitely sounds like a software issue since it always works except when booted into your personal configuration of Windows (i.e. not safe mode).  If it's really important to you, you might try doing a system restore if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the latest ATI drivers to make sure? Also plug in a DVI or VGA just for testing purposes.

Right click desktop > Screen resolution

Then click Detect on the top right.

You should see some extra screens on the view.

There is a drop down box showing display devices, if your HDMI device is listed select that and choose it as your primary display.

Comment: i have installed the latest drivers... i previously had a monitor attatched on dvi but i had to disconnect it as the ati cant run dvi and hdmi at the same time... i cant tell if the samsung is coming up on the display option as the screen is blank... and its not an extended desktop as i have no signal coming through (as the pre pro in the middle of the setup is telling me)... prepro is not problem though becase like i said it works in safemode...

Comment: You _could_ do it completely blind (i.e. without a monitor).  You could try pressing [windows key], typing "screen resolution," pressing [enter], waiting a few seconds, pressing [alt]-[c] (which is "detect"), waiting a few more seconds, pressing [alt]-[s] (which is the dropdown box that lets you pick monitors), pressing the [down] arrow key to select the other monitor, then pressing [tab] exactly seven times (if you do eight you will end up hitting cancel) to select "ok."  Then press [enter].

Comment: and if that doesn't work, I would still try holding down [Windows Key] and pressing [P] twice.  (to go from "monitor only" to "duplicate")

Comment: Also.  I would try turning up the sound on your television, pressing [Windows Key]-[U], then pressing [alt]-[n], then hitting [enter].  This will turn on the narrator.  Doing that will accomplish two things:  (1) it will make it easier to try changing settings in real time since you will now know what you're changing and (2) you will know for sure that the computer isn't locked up but instead only having display problems.